# Passing index of a @Binding array to subview

Tags: arrays, swift

I am querying a server for JSON file for Posts data, in the following format

```
struct PostsQuery: Codable {
    var posts: [Post]
    var next: String?
}

struct Post: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let body: String?

}
```

I initialise a @State variable in
MainView(), and passing it into FeedView()

```
struct MainTabView: View {
 @State private var postsQuery: PostsQuery?
   var body: some View {
     FeedView(postsQuery: $postsQuery)
       .onAppear {
        // Load JSON file into postQuery
       }
   }
}
```

In FeedView(), I'm trying to pass a single post into FeedCellView() however I can't get it to work, any kind suggestions on how I can do it? Below is my currently implementation. I get an error that Xcode can't compile and suggest I file a bug with Apple.

```
struct FeedView: View {
    
    @Binding var postsQuery: PostsQuery?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            List{
                ForEach(postsQuery?.posts.indices ?? Range(0...0), id: \.self) { index in
                    FeedCellView(post: $postsQuery.$posts[index]). // ERROR HERE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the Post object within PostQuery to be passed to FeedCellView(). Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: You should not be using indices in a `ForEach` like that. If you need a binding, use something like: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-list-or-a-foreach-from-a-binding

Comment: You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI” indicies/ranges are considered unsafe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the `posts` array itself to `ForEach`. `ForEach` has an [initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:id:content:)-2n8nd) that takes a `Binding` of a collection:

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @Binding var postsQuery: PostsQuery?

    var body: some View {
        // unwrap the postsQuery optional first
        if let postsQuery = Binding($postsQuery) {
            // here, postsQuery.posts is a Binding<[Post]>
            // you don't need "id: \.id" if Post conforms to Identifiable
            ForEach(postsQuery.posts, id: \.id) { post in
                // here, "post" is a Binding<Post>
                FeedCellView(post: post)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oof this works! I suppose this is fundamental to Swift development, really appreciate the insight as a rookie dev - I learnt a lot today. Thanks!

Comment: Also just curious how would one do it if instead postQuery is a '@State' optional? 
e.g. '@State' var postQuery: PostQuery?

Comment: @ayelvs the answer wouldn’t change. It’s just that `@State`s are a source of truth. If `postQuery`”belongs” to a parent view, then it shouldn’t be `@State`. I’m pretty sure any SwiftUI tutorial out there will include stuff like this.